# shell how to apply a function to all the files in the directory with r

Tags: r, date

I need to apply a function of filling dates to all the files in which I have imported from the directory, when running the code it shows me the following error: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors", help or suggestions I am new in R thanks

```
        path <- "C:/Data/2008/"
    files <- list.files(path =path,pattern="*.csv")
    for(file in files)
    {
      perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
      assign(
        gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
        read_delim(paste(path,file,sep=""), ";",escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(Fecha = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")), 
        trim_ws = TRUE))
      as.data.frame(file)

    }

    for (file in files) {
  file $fecha=as.Date(file $Fecha)
  orden.fecha=file [order(file $fecha),]
  lonjitud.fecha=length(orden.fecha$fecha)
  fecha.min=orden.fecha$fecha[1]
  fecha.max=orden.fecha$fecha[lonjitud.fecha]
  todas.fecha=seq(fecha.min,fecha.max,by="day")
  todas.fechas.frame<- data.frame(list(fecha=todas.fecha))
  merged.fecha<-merge(todas.fechas.frame,orden.fecha,all = T)




}
```

Comment: This could refer to a lot of things, there's a lot of lines here. It might be discernible from the code you've provided, but this is a poor question. You should be able to give evidence of your own attempt at the problem. For now, this should involve some basic debugging. You should at least be able to pinpoint the line of code where the problem occurs. Try setting `file = files[1]` and run your code outside of the loop. Which breaks it? the `traceback()` command might also be useful. Do some research, do some debugging, improve this question, then someone here might be able to help you :)

Comment: I see spaces where they don't belong (`file $fecha`) and a mixture of lower and upper case that does not seem consistent (`Fecha` / `fecha`).

Comment: you're not assigning a variable to file (i think that's why you data.frame() it, so after you run you first for loop you don't modify you file list; then you use $ but that's for accessing a variable or slot in your data.frame, which is still a list